# IP logging in ExpressionEngine always shows 127.0.0.1

Tags: ip, developer-log

It seems that both the access logs, search logs and comments in ExpressionEngine always display with a local IP address of 127.0.0.1.  How can I have EE show the actual IP address a user, search or comment is coming from, instead of 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by a proxy.  To have the logs track the correct IP address you'll need to set the IP of the proxy server(s) in your config file.  Please note, this will tell ExpressionEngine to look in additional locations in PHP for the correct IP address.

To do this, simply add the following.

> $config[‘proxy_ips’] = ‘127.0.0.1’;

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#proxy_ips